# Antialiasing with Pen

Tags: c#, graphics, antialiasing

In my code, I'm using graphics and pen to create a program that is similar to Paint. Since I've implemented a trackbar which will allow the user to change the width of the pen, I wanted to make the lines smoother. I know SmoothingMode and AntiAlias will have to be used, but I have no idea how to implement it and where. (I've omitted parts of code such as changing the color of the pen, changing the background of the panel, and erasing the drawing)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool mousePress;
    int xLast;
    int yLast;
    Graphics myGraphics;
    Pen myPen;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myGraphics = pnlBlackboard.CreateGraphics(); 
        myPen = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
        mousePress = false;
    }
    private void pnlBlackboard_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            mousePress = true;
            xLast = e.X;
            yLast = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pnlBlackboard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mousePress)
        {
            myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, xLast, yLast, e.X, e.Y);
            xLast = e.X;
            yLast = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pnlBlackboard_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, xLast, yLast, e.X, e.Y);
            mousePress = false;
        }
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        myGraphics.Dispose();
        myPen.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); 
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (trackBar1.Value == 0)
        {
            myPen.Width = 1;
        }
        else if (trackBar1.Value == 1)
        {
            myPen.Width = 4;
        }
        else if (trackBar1.Value == 2)
        {
            myPen.Width = 6;
        }
        else if (trackBar1.Value == 3)
        {
            myPen.Width = 8;
        }
        else if (trackBar1.Value == 4)
        {
            myPen.Width = 12;
        }
        else if (trackBar1.Value == 5)
        {
            myPen.Width = 20;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ugh, CreateGraphics bad.  Minimizing your form will erase everything.  Use the paint event or a graphic object from a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use before DrawLine etc.. For example:

```
myGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 12, 8);
```

Comment: I get the error "The name 'SmoothingMode' does not exist in the current context" when I try to insert the lines of code right before or after the if statement.

Comment: @Emma You need a reference to the System.Drawing.Drawing2D namespace.